# How to make this css readable?

Tags: css, minify

I want to edit this CSS [file](http://static.blogg.no/blogs/screen.css) but as you see, it does not look like a normal CSS style.

```
html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}legend{color:#000;}body{font:13px/1.231 arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;*font-size:small;*font:x-small;}table{font-size:inherit;font:100%;}pre,code,kbd,samp,tt{font-family:monospace;*font-size:108%;line-height:100%;}body{text-align:center;}#ft{clear:both;}#doc,#doc2,#doc3,#doc4,.yui-t1,.yui-t2,.yui-t3,.yui-t4,.yui-t5,.yui-t6,.yui-t7{margin:auto;text-align:left;width:57.69em;*width:56.301em;min-width:750px;}#doc2{width:73.074em;*width:71.313em;}#doc3{margin:auto 10px;width:auto;}#doc4{width:74.923em;*width:73.117em;}.yui-b{position:relative;}.yui-b{_position:static;}#yui-main .yui-b{position:static;}#yui-main{width:100%;}.yui-t1 #yui-main,.yui-t2 #yui-main,.yui-t3 #yui-main{float:right;margin-left:-25em;}.yui-t4 #yui-main,.yui-t5 #yui-main,.yui-t6 #yui-main{float:left;margin-right:-25em;}.yui-t1 .yui-b{float:left;width:12.3207em;*width:12.0106em;}.yui-t1 #yui-main .yui-b{margin-left:13.3207em;*margin-left:13.0106em;}.yui-t2 .yui-b{float:left;width:13.8456em;*width:13.512em;}.yui-t2 #yui-main .yui-b{margin-left:14.8456em;*margin-left:14.512em;}.yui-t3 .yui-b{float:left;width:23.0759em;*width:22.52em;}.yui-t3 #yui-main .yui-b{margin-left:24.0759em;*margin-left:23.52em;}.yui-t4 .yui-b{float:right;width:13.8456em;*width:13.512em;}.yui-t4 #yui-main .yui-b{margin-right:14.8456em;*margin-right:14.512em;}.yui-t5 .yui-b{float:right;width:18.4608em;*width:18.016em;}.yui-t5 #yui-main .yui-b{margin-right:19.4608em;*margin-right:19.016em;}.yui-t6 .yui-b{float:right;width:23.0759em;*width:22.52em;}.yui-t6 #yui-main .yui-b{margin-right:24.0759em;*margin-right:23.52em;}.yui-t7 #yui-main .yui-b{display:block;margin:0 0 1em 0;}#yui-main .yui-b{float:none;width:auto;}.yui-g .yui-gb .yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-g,.yui-gb .yui-gb,.yui-gb .yui-gc,.yui-gb .yui-gd,.yui-gb .yui-ge,.yui-gb .yui-gf,.yui-gb .yui-u,.yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-gc .yui-g,.yui-gd .yui-u{float:left;margin-left:2%;width:32%;}.yui-gb .yui-gb .yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-gc .yui-u{*margin-left:1.8%;_margin-left:4%;}.yui-g .yui-gb .yui-u{_margin-left:.8%;}.yui-gb .yui-u{float:right;}.yui-gb div.first{margin-left:0;float:left;}.yui-g .yui-gb div.first,.yui-gb .yui-gb div.first{*margin-right:0;*width:32%;_width:31.7%;}.yui-gb .yui-gc div.first,.yui-gb .yui-gd div.first{*margin-right:0;}.yui-gb .yui-gd .yui-u{*width:66%;_width:61.2%;}.yui-gb .yui-gd div.first{*width:31%;_width:29.5%;}.yui-g .yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-gc .yui-u{width:32%;_float:right;margin-right:0;_margin-left:0;}.yui-gb .yui-gc div.first{width:66%;*float:left;*margin-left:0;}.yui-gb .yui-ge .yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-gf .yui-u{margin:0;}.yui-g .yui-u,.yui-g .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gb,.yui-g .yui-gc,.yui-g .yui-gd,.yui-g .yui-ge,.yui-g .yui-gf,.yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-gd .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gc .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-u{float:right;}.yui-g .yui-gc div.first,.yui-g .yui-ge div.first,.yui-g div.first,.yui-gc div.first,.yui-gc div.first div.first,.yui-gd div.first,.yui-ge div.first,.yui-gf div.first{float:left;}.yui-g .yui-g .yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-g .yui-u,.yui-gc .yui-g .yui-u,.yui-gd .yui-g .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-g .yui-u,.yui-gf .yui-g .yui-u{width:49%;*width:48.1%;*margin-left:0;}.yui-g .yui-g div.first{*margin:0;}.yui-gb .yui-g div.first{*margin-right:4%;_margin-right:1.3%;}.yui-gb .yui-gb .yui-u{_margin-left:.7%;}.yui-gb .yui-g div.first,.yui-gb .yui-gb div.first{*margin-left:0;}.yui-gc .yui-g .yui-u,.yui-gd .yui-g .yui-u{*width:48.1%;*margin-left:0;}.yui-g .yui-u,.yui-g .yui-g,.yui-g .yui-gb,.yui-g .yui-gc,.yui-g .yui-gd,.yui-g .yui-ge,.yui-g .yui-gf{width:49.1%;}.yui-g .yui-gb div.first,.yui-gb div.first,.yui-gc div.first,.yui-gd div.first{margin-left:0;}.yui-g .yui-gc div.first,.yui-gc div.first,.yui-gd .yui-g,.yui-gd .yui-u{width:66%;}.yui-gd div.first,.yui-gb .yui-gd div.first{width:32%;}.yui-g .yui-gd div.first{_width:29.9%;}.yui-ge .yui-u,.yui-ge .yui-g,.yui-gf div.first{width:24%;}.yui-gb .yui-ge div.yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-gf div.yui-u{float:right;}.yui-gb .yui-ge div.first,.yui-gb .yui-gf div.first{float:left;}.yui-ge div.first,.yui-gf .yui-g,.yui-gf .yui-u{width:74.2%;}.yui-gb .yui-ge .yui-u,.yui-gb .yui-gf div.first{*width:24%;_width:20%;}.yui-gb .yui-ge div.first,.yui-gb .yui-gf .yui-u{*width:73.5%;_width:65.5%;}#bd:after,.yui-g:after,.yui-gb:after,.yui-gc:after,.yui-gd:after,.yui-ge:after,.yui-gf:after{content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}#bd,.yui-g,.yui-gb,.yui-gc,.yui-gd,.yui-ge,.yui-gf{zoom:1;}.yui-gb .yui-u{float:left;}h1{font-size:138.5%;}h2{font-size:123.1%;}h3{font-size:108%;}h1,h2,h3{margin:1em 0;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,strong{font-weight:bold;}abbr,acronym{border-bottom:1px dotted #000;cursor:help;}em{font-style:italic;}blockquote,ul,ol,dl{margin:1em;}ol,ul,dl{margin-left:2em;}ol li{list-style:decimal outside;}ul li{list-style:disc outside;}dl dd{margin-left:1em;}th,td{border:1px solid #000;padding:.5em;}th{font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}caption{margin-bottom:.5em;text-align:center;}p,fieldset,table,pre{margin-bottom:1em;}input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea{width:12.25em;*width:11.9em;}*{padding:0;margin:0;}#TB_window{font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333;}#TB_secondLine{font:10px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#666;}#TB_window a:link{color:#666;}#TB_window a:visited{color:#666;}#TB_window a:hover{color:#000;}#TB_window a:active{color:#666;}#TB_window a:focus{color:#666;}#TB_overlay{position:fixed;z-index:100;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;}.TB_overlayMacFFBGHack{background:url(http://static.blogg.no/lib/ext/thickbox/macFFBgHack.png) repeat;}.TB_overlayBG{background-color:#000;filter:alpha(opacity=75);-moz-opacity:.75;opacity:.75;}* html #TB_overlay{position:absolute;height:expression(document.body.scrollHeight>document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight:document.body.offsetHeight+'px');}#TB_window{position:fixed;background:#fff;z-index:102;color:#000;display:none;border:4px solid #525252;text-align:left;top:50%;left:50%;}* html #TB_window{position:absolute;margin-top:expression(0 - parseInt(this.offsetHeight / 2)+(TBWindowMargin = document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)+'px');}#TB_window img#TB_Image{display:block;margin:15px 0 0 15px;border-right:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;border-top:1px solid #666;border-left:1px solid #666;}#TB_caption{height:25px;padding:7px 30px 10px 25px;float:left;}#TB_closeWindow{height:25px;padding:11px 25px 10px 0;float:right;}#TB_closeAjaxWindow{padding:7px 10px 5px 0;margin-bottom:1px;text-align:right;float:right;}#TB_ajaxWindowTitle{float:left;padding:7px 0 5px 10px;margin-bottom:1px;}#TB_title{background-color:#e8e8e8;height:27px;}#TB_ajaxContent{clear:both;padding:2px 15px 15px 15px;overflow:auto;text-align:left;line-height:1.4em;}#TB_ajaxContent.TB_modal{padding:15px;}#TB_ajaxContent p{padding:5px 0 5px 0;}#TB_load{position:fixed;display:none;height:13px;width:208px;z-index:103;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-6px 0 0 -104px;}* html #TB_load{position:absolute;margin-top:expression(0 - parseInt(this.offsetHeight / 2)+(TBWindowMargin = document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)+'px');}#TB_HideSelect{z-index:99;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background-color:#fff;border:none;filter:alpha(opacity=0);-moz-opacity:0;opacity:0;height:100%;width:100%;}* html #TB_HideSelect{position:absolute;height:expression(document.body.scrollHeight>document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight:document.body.offsetHeight+'px');}#TB_iframeContent{clear:both;border:none;margin-bottom:-1px;margin-top:1px;_margin-bottom:1px;}.clearfix:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0;}.clearfix{display:inline-block;}html[xmlns] .clearfix{display:block;}* html .clearfix{height:1%;}h1,h1 a,h2,h2 a,h3,h3 a,h4,h4 a,h5,h5 a{font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;}h1{font-size:200%;margin:5px 0 5px 0;}h2{font-size:175%;margin:0 0 10px 0;}h3{font-size:120%;margin:0 0 5px 0;}h4{font-size:110%;margin:0 0 5px 0;}a{text-decoration:none;}#wrapper{margin:0;padding:0 20px 10px 20px;}#header{padding:20px;height:80px;cursor:pointer;}body.front #header{cursor:auto;}#main{overflow:hidden;}#side{margin:0;overflow:hidden;padding:0 0 0 15px;}.breadcrumbs{margin:0 0 10px 0;padding-top:5px;font-size:80%;}body .entry{margin:0 0 20px 0;clear:both;}body .entry *{line-height:1.4;}.entry h2{margin:0 0 5px 0;}.entry ul li{list-style-position:outside;list-style-type:square;}.entry ol{list-style-position:outside;list-style-type:decimal;}.entry li{margin-left:40px;}.entry li li{margin-left:20px;}.entry img[align="left"]{margin:0 10px 5px 0;}.entry img[align="right"]{margin:0 0 5px 10px;}.entry .meta,.entry .tags{font-size:11px;clear:both;}.entry .meta{margin:10px 0;}.entry .tags{margin:0 0 10px 0;}.entry .meta ul,.entry .tags ul{display:inline;padding:0;margin:0;}.entry .meta ul li,.entry .tags ul li{list-style:none;display:inline;margin:0 5px 0 5px;padding:0;}.entry table{margin:10px 0;border-collapse:collapse;}.entry table th{padding:3px 10px;font-weight:bold;}.entry table tr{border-bottom:1px dotted;}.entry table td{padding:3px 10px;}p{margin:0 0 14px 0;}small{font-size:90%;}strong,b{font-weight:bold;}em,i{font-style:italic;}code,kbd{font-family:monospace;}abbr{border-bottom:1px dotted;}ul{margin:0;}ul li{margin:0 0 3px 0;list-style:none;}.pad{padding:10px;}a.thickbox img{padding:0;border:1px solid #000;margin:5px 10px 5px 0;}#profile h3{display:inline;}#profile a img{background-color:#fff;padding:3px;border:2px solid;margin:5px 10px 5px 5px;float:right;}#side h3{clear:both;}#newcomment{padding:10px 0 10px 10px;clear:both;}#newcomment div{width:100%;margin-bottom:15px;float:left;}#newcomment label{width:280px;display:block;}#newcomment input{width:280px;}#newcomment textarea,#newcomment input#comment_authorurl{width:575px;}#newcomment textarea{height:100px;}#newcomment #comment_remember{width:16px;height:16px;}#newcomment #comment_remember_wrapper label{display:inline;}#newcomment #comment_remember_wrapper{padding-top:5px;}#newcomment #comment_author_wrapper,#newcomment #comment_authoremail_wrapper,#newcomment #comment_submit_wrapper,#newcomment #comment_remember_wrapper{width:280px;margin-right:15px;}#newcomment #comment_submit{padding:3px 10px;}#comments .comment{padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;clear:both;}#comments img.avatar{border:1px solid;padding:3px;float:right;margin:0 0 10px 10px;}#comments .owner{border-top:1px dotted;border-bottom:1px dotted;background:#eef;color:#000;}#comments .user{border-top:1px dotted;border-bottom:1px dotted;background:#ffc;color:#000;}img.asin{margin:0 4px 4px 0;}div.bloggrevyen_links{margin:10px 0;padding:10px 0;border-top:1px dotted;border-bottom:1px dotted;}div.bloggrevyen_links div p{font-weight:bold;}#side div{margin-bottom:15px;}#footer{padding:20px;border-top:1px dotted;font-size:80%;}.fb_like{display:none;}.fblike{margin:20px 0 15px 0;}.mna-footer{text-align:center;}.mna-footer-text,.mna-footer-logo{margin-bottom:5px;}.mna-footer-appended{padding:10px 0 10px 0;font-size:11px;}
```

My questions are:

1. What kind of CSS file is this?
2. How to reformat it so that it looks clean and nice like a regular css file?

Comment: That is a minified CSS. The spaces are removed to reduce the file size.

Comment: Most editors will reformat it for you, or you can use an online tool like http://www.lonniebest.com/formatcss/ or http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/

Comment: Any tip on how to format it back to original(regular) css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a normal CSS file. It has just been minified.

You can unminify CSS files by running them through "[beautifiers](https://google.com/#q=css%20beautifier)".

They're also called "[unminifiers](https://www.google.com/#q=unminify+css)".

Typically, you "minify" your code when you're ready to move it to production in order to make the file size smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It's minified/obfuscated CSS.

In theory there could be a performance benefit, but it's negligible for a file of this size. It's more likely the author did not want someone copying/pasting it.

You can use another online tool to un-obfuscate it: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a perfectly normal CSS File.

If you have dreamweaver go to Commands, Apply Source Formatting.

Alternatively use a thirdparty beautifier like http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simply beautify it with, works instantly: [http://minifybeautify.com](http://minifybeautify.com/)